# How to read Snowflake table from Spark connector when the table was created with quotes around it?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

I know how to read from Snowflake table with Spark connector like below:

```
df = spark.read.format("snowflake") \
               .options(**sfParams) # This is a dict with all the SF creds stored \
               .option('dbtable', 'TABLE1').load()
```

This works perfectly fine. But if the table was created with quotes around it in Snowflake like `CREATE TABLE DB1.SCHEMA1."MY.TABLE2"`, spark is not able to format it. I tried like

```
df = spark.read.format("snowflake") \
               .options(**sfParams) # This is a dict with all the SF creds stored \
               .option('dbtable', '"MY.TABLE2"').load()
```

But its throwing `invalid URL prefix found in: 'MY.TABLE2'`

Comment: Have you tried escaping the **"** with a \ ?

Comment: @Sergiu yes same error.

Comment: @Sergiu sorry I was doing something wrong. Please reply to this question with your answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using objects with [identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html) in code, they need to be escaped, like:

```
'"MY.TABLE2"'
```

should be:

```
'\"MY.TABLE2\"'
```